# In what way are the brackets of this regex "mismatched"?

Tags: c++, regex

Consider this C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    regex_match("'c'", std::regex("'[\x00-\x7F]'"));
    std::cout << "Reached!";
}
```

When I compile it with clang++ 8.0.0, it crashes at runtime with the following error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::regex_error: The expression contained mismatched [ and ].
Abort trap: 6
```

But in how far are the brackets mismatched? I have an opening bracket and it is closed by a closing bracket. What is my error?

Comment: Should it be `"'[\\x00-\\x7F]'"`?

Comment: Yes. That's it! Thank you so much. If you write an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: The reason for the crash is the `\x00` is causing an end of string to be injected, and the parser is ignoring the rest. It would _generally_ work with any other character code

Comment: Or you could use raw literal strings where you don't need to escape your escape. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal  `std::regex(R("'[\x00-\x7F]'"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is already mentioned in the comments several hours ago. Since the commenters don't seem to be coming back, I will summarize the point here.

Here, `\x00` is just `\0`, which denotes the end of a C-style string. A `regex` is constructed with a C-style string, so what the constructor sees is really `"'["` instead of the desired `"'[\x00-\x7F]'"`. In other words, C-style strings cannot contain the `\0` character. This explains why the library complains that your brackets are mismatched.

Since regex allows direct use of escaping, you can let the constructor see the characters `\x00`. The `\` itself needs to be escaped, so it is `"\\x00"`. Note that you are passing four characters to the constructor in this case, instead of one. Same for `\x7F`.

```
std::regex("'[\\x00-\\x7F]'")
```

Alternatively, you can use raw strings, so you don't have to escape the backslashes.

```
std::regex(R"('[\x00-\x7F]')")
```